# How can I run bash in a docker container?

Tags: bash, docker

I am able to run arbitrary shell commands in a container created from docker/whalesay image.

```
$ docker run docker/whalesay ls -l
total 56
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  931 May 25  2015 ChangeLog
...
```

However, I am unable to run `bash` in a container created from this image:

```
$ docker run docker/whalesay bash

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
7ce600cc9904        docker/whalesay     "bash"                   5 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                           loving_mayer
```

Why did it not work? How can I make it work?

Comment: What happens when you do *docker exec -it 7ce600cc9904 /bin/bash* ?

Comment: @SilentMonk It fails with this error: `Error response from daemon: Container 7ce600cc990463518cc8fa073014942d99347b4ff0d6927031c8a839e8a8803e is not running`

Answer (score 633, accepted):

If you `docker run` without attaching a tty, and only call `bash`, then bash finds nothing to do, and it exits. That's because by default, a container is non-interactive, and a shell that runs in non-interactive mode expects a script to run. Absent that, it will exit.

To run a disposable new container, you can simply attach a tty and standard input:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash <image-name-or-id>
```

Or to prevent the above container from being disposed, run it without `--rm`.

Or to enter a running container, use `exec` instead:

```
docker exec -it <container-name-or-id> bash
```

---

In comments you asked

> Do you know what is the difference between this and `docker run -it --entrypoint bash docker/whalesay`?

In the two commands above, you are specifying `bash` as the `CMD`. In this command, you are specifying `bash` as the `ENTRYPOINT`.

Every container is run using a combination of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`. If you (or the image) does not specify `ENTRYPOINT`, the default entrypoint is `/bin/sh -c`.

So in the earlier two commands, if you run `bash` as the `CMD`, and the default `ENTRYPOINT` is used, then the container will be run using

```
/bin/sh -c bash
```

If you specify `--entrypoint bash`, then instead it runs

```
bash <command>
```

Where `<command>` is the `CMD` specified in the image (if any is specified).

Comment: Thanks. `docker run -it docker/whalesay bash` works. Do you know what is the difference between this and `docker run -it --entrypoint bash docker/whalesay`?

Comment: why does it need "-i" ? as far as I understand, attaching is the default, so wouldn't stdin of the bash stay open anyway?

Comment: What should I do when `bash` isn't found in the `PATH`.

Comment: @buhtz If you know what the path is, you can use that, e.g. change to `/usr/local/bin/bash` or whatever. But also keep in mind an image may not have bash, and maybe you should try `sh` or `/bin/sh` instead. It will depend on the image contents.

Comment: How do I know what an "image have" when I just write `<image-name-or-id>`?

Comment: @buhtz there is no way to predict it. Many image have `bash`; some do not, but might have `sh` instead. There are even images that have no shell inside at all (there are single-file Go binary images like that, for example).