# My mysql docker container keeps exiting after running exec command

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, fedora

I am using a script that I made to ease things on my docker. The script basically is

```
docker run -dit -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=user123 --name lar -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7
```

This one creates a docker container with the name *lar*.

---

The other script to create a database in my container is:

```
echo "Enter database name to create: "
read dbName
mysqlScript="CREATE DATABASE $dbName;"
echo "Running script $mysqlScript"
docker exec -i lar mysql -uroot -puser123 <<< $mysqlScript
```

They both worked perfectly when I was using them on windows WSL but now there seems to be some trouble. Whenever I try to run the `createDB.sh` file, the container suddenly stops. Its not only for script file but whenever I try to manually exec into the container, the container goes down.

this is the log

```
2022-05-01 16:19:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.38-1debian10 started.
```

---

And anytime I restart the container and repeat the same process, the same thing happens.

---

Checked links:
[How can I run bash in a new container of a docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43308319/how-can-i-run-bash-in-a-new-container-of-a-docker-image)

[docker run exited right away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114411/docker-run-exited-right-away)

---

If anyone wants to check out the actual script files:
https://github.com/sugamkarki/docker-scripts/tree/master/mysql

Comment: "*This one creates a docker image with the name lar.*" - It creates a *container* with name `lar`.

Comment: Can you check the line endings of the files (especially the `.sh` file)? They should be set to linux line endings (`lf`).

Comment: I ran ```file mysql.sh``` and I got ```mysql.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable```. I am not sure if that was what you were asking

Comment: No, not really. Can you try opening the file in `nano` or `vi`? If you see something like `^M` at the end of each line, then the problem is most probably related to line ending encoding.

Comment: Oh there are no any ```^M``` thingies. When I was on widows, I had the ```bad interpreter``` issue and had used ```dos2unix``` to fix it. When that happened, the file totally refused to run but now the container is running and I can see it in the ```docker ps```.

Comment: I see nothing wrong, maybe changing `docker run -dit` to `docker run -d`.

Comment: @Philippe just tried that, the problem persists

Comment: Now remove `-p 3306:3306` temporarily, to see if it improves.

Comment: @Philippe sorry, its not working. I have scripts for psotgreSQL in the similar format and its working as expected in that one. Is it an issue with the mysql version that I'm trying to use? But it was working fine on windows

Comment: I ran your scripts in Ubuntu, without any problem.

Comment: Yeah they used to work but suddenly I started getting these weird errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244390/discussion-between-s-karki-and-philippe).